# How can I implement a .NET Core performance profiler via code

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-core

I developed a middleware that starts a Stopwatch before invoking next and stops when the response is available, I then log the elapsed time after that.

This is all good. But it doesn't provide me breakdown, ie: within the call which method invocations took how much? for example: if I have 4 method calls in a request, I would like to know each one's duration.

I assume, middleware is not enough for this purpose, without having to put decorators all over the place, how can i get this done?

Thanks.

Comment: Without touching called code? It can hardly be done (AFAIK) without also impacting performance (or greatly reducing accuracy). Isn't more or less what a plain Profiler does? You can _sample_ the stacktrace often enough but optimizations will give you almost useless or hard to read results (and performance will be greatly affected for a very poor accuracy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you have to manually instrument most interesting pieces of code.

Although, there are solutions for IL injection (see [MSIL Injection](https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/msil-injection) page on PostSharp website), I don't think that it is possible to inject code in arbitrary places without changing existing code base. However, in many cases it is relatively easy to instrument large portion of existing code (given it is reasonably well separated into modules) using decorators. For example add custom profiling `DelegatingHandler` to `HttpClient` or use profiling `SqlConnection` factory.

In order to inspect call hierarchy and latency you can utilize [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/), it's built-in decorators and `RenderPlainText()` method. Or you can utilize [Metrics.NET](https://github.com/Recognos/Metrics.NET) library to inspect throughput related metrics such as histogram and counter.